# How to Create a Template using Magnolia stk?

Tags: magnolia

I am starting one project on Magnolia Blossom. I want to know -

- How to Create a Template Using magnolia stk ?
- How and where it is configured in the project ?

I am very new to this technology. 
Can anyone having idea about this.

Please reply as soon as possible .

Comment: If you do not understand just suggest how to correct it before down voting it. because it does not make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

I would start from this [tutorial](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/My+first+template) which does not use the stk, but it gives you an idea how magnolia works. 
Therefore you can try to extend a component from their demo site following this [guide](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS/Extending+the+stkArticle+template) . 
And [here](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS45/Standard+Templating+Kit) you will find the documentation that tells you how to create a site with the stk (this documentation is a bit outdated but it is good for start), first thing that you need to do is to define a prototype for your site, and from there you can create actual website.